# submit form at each step using Jquery form wizard

Tags: model-view-controller, jquery-plugins

I am using  Jquery Form wizard plugin in a MVC application. http://thecodemine.org/
I have a form with 4 steps. in one of step i have upload functionality.
I want submit functionality at each step and also back and next steps. later steps are optional.

I was able to add a submit button in navigation. On clicking it, form data related to active step is only submitted and other data is null.

For more clarity of my issue:
View :

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="/Controller/Action">
    <div id="fieldWrapper">
        <fieldset class="step fieldset" id="first">
            <legend class="legend">First step</legend>
            Some input controls
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="step fieldset" id="second">
            <legend class="legend">Second step</legend>
            some more input controls (optional)
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="step fieldset" id="third">
            <legend class="legend">Third step</legend>
            some more input controls with filu upload
            (optional)
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="step fieldset" id="fourth">
            <legend class="legend">Fourth step</legend>
            some more input controls (optional)
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id="demoNavigation">
        <input class="navigation_button" id="back" value="Back" type="reset" />
        <button type="submit" id="submitBtn">Submit and Finish</button>
        <input class="navigation_button" id="next" value="Next" type="submit" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#myform").formwizard({
            validationEnabled: true,
            focusFirstInput: false,
            disableUIStyles: true,
            textSubmit: 'Submit and Finish',
            textNext: 'Continue to next step',
            next: "input:submit"
        }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Updated the Jquery.form.wizard.js to so that the submit button hides at last step.
Now on each step i have submit button and navigation button.

When i submit form on second step, form data in second step is only posted and rest is not posted.

I went through the samples but could not find the appropriate one.
Can anyone suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: I had no issue achieving this. Please ensure your fields are in a fieldset tag; failing that paste markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the documentation and jquery.form.wizard.js file to get beeter understanding of what is done.

I just have to write some script as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#myform").formwizard({
            validationEnabled: true,
            focusFirstInput: false,
            disableUIStyles: true,
            textSubmit: 'Submit and Finish',
            textNext: 'Continue to next step',
            next: "input:submit"
        }
        );
    });
    $('#submitBtn').click(function () {
        var stepInfo = $('#myform').formwizard('state');
        for (var i = 0; i < stepInfo.activatedSteps.length; i++) {
            stepInfo.steps.filter("#" + stepInfo.activatedSteps[i]).find(":input").not(".wizard-ignore").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
</script>
```